# How to append values to existing comma delimited csv (excel) file

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, openxlsx

I have an existing CSV-file with 4 columns (comma delimited, so all values in one column in excel) 
[image]

How do I write a code to add for example the value '10' to every row (that is the length) 

 Also, how do I add a string to these rows?

Ideal output would be: 
[image]

I have tried

```
a = np.array([2,5])
b = np.array([1000,3000])
c = np.array([10])
d = np.array(["both"])

combined = np.array(list(zip(a,b,c,d)))

-- output of combined: --
array([['2', '1000', '10', 'both']], dtype='<U11')
```

When I use np.savetxt, I encounter the error message saying:

```
np.savetxt("testfile.csv", combined, delimiter=",")  

Error:
Mismatch between array dtype ('<U11') and format specifier
```

Can anyone spot the solution? Do I need to format the np.savetxt? If so, then what to be add? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the mixed type of the array, you need to specify the formatter when flushing into a file:

Try:

```
np.savetxt("testfile.csv", combined, fmt='%s',delimiter=",")
```

Every entry gets casted as a string before writing.

To solve the issue in the comments:

```
a = np.array([2,5])
b = np.array([1000,3000])
c = np.array([10]*2)
d = np.array(["both"]*2)
```

This should give you two rows.

Comment: Thanks that worked but why is only the first element in each list created? Output in csv is now: 2,1000,10,both (which is only one row)

Comment: This is because `zip` stops at the shortest length, and your arrays `b` and `c` only have one entry.

Comment: How do I tackle that problem? I tried with looping in a range with length of a. Still does not work. I was thinking of adding zeros to match size of other arrays but it feels like a stupid way to do so..